# Как решить проблему с воспроизведением звука на Windows 11?

Tags: windows, аудио, windows-11

Кто нибудь, помогите с такой проблемой на Windows 11. Если захожу например в ютуб, или любой браузер, хочу включить какое-нибудь видео, звука совсем нет. Когда делаю проверку звука, происходит ошибка. А вот если запускаю видео из папки на компьютере через медиаплеер, то звук есть. Как это можно исправить? Раньше подобных проблем не возникало. Перепробывала уже много способов, ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Переустанови аудио драйвер. Если не помогло, установи пакет кодеков (например - "K-Lite codec pack") https://www.codecguide.com/